# Sharepoint add a field to all lists/document libraries in a site collection

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I got it working with adding it to a specified list, but I want to go trough all lists in the site collection. I just cant find out whats making this not work.

Code that works for one list:

```
    void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://asdf:150/sites/test"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists["test8"];

                    //Needed?
                    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                    string mainLocation = list.Fields.Add("New Field", SPFieldType.Text, false, false, null);
                    readOnly(list, mainLocation);

                    //Add to default view (will be removed after testing)
                    SPView view = list.DefaultView;
                    defaultView(view, "New Field");
                }
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

I want to add the field to all lists in the site collection, but I dont know what I could be doing wrong, this is what I have so far.

```
void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://asdf:150/sites/test"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    //Needed?
                    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    try
                    {
                        SPListCollection lists = web.Lists; // ??
                        foreach (SPList list in lists)
                        {
                            string mainLocation = list.Fields.Add("New Field", SPFieldType.Text, false, false, null);
                            readOnly(list, mainLocation);

                            //Add to default view (will be removed after testing)
                            SPView view = list.DefaultView;
                            defaultView(view, "New Field");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        // some exception handling
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        //web.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Helper methods

```
void readOnly(SPList list, string name)
{
    SPField listField = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(name);
    listField.ReadOnlyField = true;
    listField.Update();
}

void defaultView(SPView view, string field)
{
    view.ViewFields.Add(field);
    view.Update();
}
```

Hope any any one of you are smarter then me here :)

Comment: So what is wrong? Do you have an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run your code and you have 2 main problems.
1. Default view can bu null in some lists. So you should check it.

```
SPView view = list.DefaultView;
if(view != null)
{
    defaultView(view, "New Field");
}
```

2. SPListCollection is modified, when you make changes to list. You should have 
temporary IEnumerable for iterating through lists.

```
using System.Linq;

SPListCollection listCollection = web.Lists;
IEnumerable<SPList> lists = listCollection.Cast<SPList>();
foreach (SPList list in lists)
{
```

3. Do not ignore Excaptions. Add some code to catch block, that can help you.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Super! I added:             catch (Exception ex)
            {
                label.Text = ex.Message;
            } to add it to the label of the wap part where this button was located. And I got the exeption: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. Very helpfull!

Comment: Now I just need to find out why Cast is not recognized.

Comment: I don't think `Cast` is an instance method of `SPListCollection`. It's not listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistcollection_methods.aspx. Note that there is a `GetEnumerator` and `GetTypedEnumerator<T>` though.

Comment: Good tip, Im trying to make that work(compile at all), but no luck so far :) Setting as accepted answer when I find the correct syntax for IEnumerable<SPList> lists = listCollection.Cast<SPList>();.

Comment: Thank you so much for that, now it compiles, but still getting the same error, posting my full code in an answer so you can see better.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I caught is that you are only checking all the lists in the root SPWeb of the site collection.

The root SPWeb can also have child SPWebs that you will need to iterate through.

Aside from that, it would help if you specified what exactly is not working or "wrong"?

Comment: Thank you for that tip, I will probably have to go trough that too. I will remember to specify what is going wrong the next time :) What was going wrong, was that it was not doing anything, I could not see that any lists was changed, and I did not have somewhere to check the exception.